# Typescript compiling very slowly

Tags: typescript

Typescript has been a great tool for us thus far, but we have a fairly large index.d.ts(approx 4700 lines), any change to the file takes approx 50-55 secs to transpile which has now become a bottleneck in our development process.

I was wondering if splitting the index.d.ts file into smaller files would help?
It would be really helpful is someone could please provide me some reference as to how we could speed things up.

Also i am having this issue wherein i have some errors being throw when i run `tsc --watch` in the command-line, but there are no errors(red squiggly underlines) when i view the code in vscode, not sure why this is happening. I am guessing this has got something to do with versioning.

Here are the versions i am using

`"typescript": "^3.6.2"` => typescript version in `package.json` *devDependency

`version 3.6.2` => Version Showing in the Bottom-Right of VsCode

`Version 3.9.2` => When i run `tsc --version` globally

Here is the output for `npx tsc --extendedDiagnostics`

<-------------Start Of Test-------------->

Files:                         649

Lines:                      173670

Nodes:                      642119

Identifiers:                227674

Symbols:                    140703

Types:                          76

Instantiations:                  0

Memory used:               213504K

Assignability cache size:        0

Identity cache size:             0

Subtype cache size:              0

Strict subtype cache size:       0

I/O Read time:               0.05s

Parse time:                  1.01s

ResolveTypeReference time:   0.02s

ResolveModule time:          0.27s

Program time:                1.46s

Bind time:                   0.80s

Total time:                  2.26s

<-------------End Of Test-------------->

The `tsconfig.json` file

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "artifacts",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "src/index.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/assets/*"
  ],
  "types": [
    "react",
    "react-native",
    "jest"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "android",
    "ios",
    "artifacts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Any Help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Thanks Regards.

Comment: can you provide log from diagnostic build `npx tsc --extendedDiagnostics` and tsconfig.json?

Comment: @Radik I have updated the question, this seemed pretty fast but command `tsc --watch` is pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

have you exclude `outDir` directory as follow or maybe you have some additional directories that should be excluded?

updated

try to change `filesGlob` to `include`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "artifacts",
  },
  "include": [
    "src/index.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/assets/*"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "artifacts", "coverage"]
}
```

Comment: Yes i have, sorry i forgot to add the tsconfig file, i have added it to the question.

Comment: @AmolGupta try to change filesGlob to include

Comment: So yeah i did try that, i am using `"include": ["./src/**/*"]` as provided in the documentation, i deleted the artifacts folder to check, but now when i run `tsc --watch` it is not generating a new (artifacts) folder.

Comment: @AmolGupta did you also remove `"incremental": true`? is just `tsc` itself did not show any errors?

Comment: So I was able to get the artifacts folder and yes running tsc by itself also showed the errors.